# Cannot start npm serve on MacOS, IntelliJ ultimate on vuejs project

Tags: node.js, macos, vue.js, npm, intellij-idea

I am failing to start `npm serve` at *Run/Debug Configuration* in IntelliJ.
But doing it separately in *Terminal* within IntelliJ or on plain console works.

**What's going on? How to solve that?**

Here's what the *Run* console shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run serve --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

> pwdstorage@0.1.0 serve
> node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service serve

env: node: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

As mentioned before running the command

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run serve --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
```

on a terminal will properly work; even in IntelliJ.

At *IntelliJ/Preferences.../Languages & Frameworks/Node.js and NPM* the *Node interpreter* is set to */usr/local/bin/node* and the Package manager is set to */usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm* They both do exist.

What the frag is going on?
I would love to get a deeper understanding of the whole thing and do appreciate any inseide views on this.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `node` is not on your `$PATH`; on MacOSX the environment variables differ between GUI applications and within the terminal. Terminal environment is only available to applications started from terminal.
To solve this problem, IDEA tries to load terminal environment by executing some scripts on startup, but it seems that it can't retrieve all needed stuff in your case - thus the issue. As a workaround, you can try starting IDEA [from terminal](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line#h_7bab70ec-bb3a-48c2-b8b8-993ea6abaffd).

Some links you may find useful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications.. The problem is that the way to define system-wide environment variables on Mac changes from one version to another (even minor system updates may break your environment)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That does work. Starting it from the terminal does the job.
In my case I build a starter script

    #! /bin/bash
    /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea &

The next two nice things would to have the opened terminal window automatically closed and link it with a proper icon to place on the desktop. If anyone can help, go ahead!-)

Answer (score 0):

As [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) answered, it did help. Thank you for your help!
Starting it from the terminal does the job.

In my case I build a starter script

```
#! /bin/bash
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea &
```

I am running the ultimate version of IntelliJ. The CE version does have another path to start!

The next two nice things to have would be

- to have the opened terminal window automatically closed
- link it with a proper icon placed on the desktop.

If anyone can help, go ahead!-)